# Environment.IsDevelopment() return always false in Docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, environment-variables

I Dockerized a .Net 7 API application.
I got blocked by some cors not being set since `appBuilder.Environment.IsDevelopment()` in Program.cs is always returning false when I run the application as a docker container.

If I run the application in **debug form visual studio** is works fine. I see that in my launch.settings it is setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to Development.

```
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
```

However when I **run** my application **from docker**, specifically docker compose, specifying the environment variables like following:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    xxxapi:
        environment:
        - DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
        ports:
            - '28227:80'
            - '44392:443'
        container_name: xxx.Api
        image: xxx.azurecr.io/core/xxxapi:latest
```

The application returns false when I call IsDevelopment() of IWebHostEnvironment.

I also ran env in the docker container terminal to double check if the variables are set correctly, and they are listed correctly:

```
# env
DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
HOSTNAME=d9a220fb17bc
HOME=/root
DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
DOTNET_VERSION=7.0.9
TERM=xterm
...
```

Lastly, I tried to set those env vars also in the build dockerfile, but it was a desperate attempt and in fact it did not work.

What can I do to tell the application running in a container that should run in Development mode?

Update:
I printed the following information:

```
isDev = webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment(),
env = webHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName,
allEnvs = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()
```

and here is the output

```
{
  "isDev": false,
  "env": "\"Development\"",
  "allEnvs": {
    "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "\"Development\"",
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "\"Development\"",
    "DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER": "true",
    ...
```

It looks like even though the environment is set to Development, the method IsDevelopment() still returns null

Comment: I don't see anything missing....in your setup.  could you also add a Logger.LogWarn call somewhere to capture the value of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT and DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT (using environment-variable reading code directly) .. as a sanity check?

Comment: @granadaCoder yes, I create an endpoint to get those info, and it looks like the variable is read correctly by .Net, nonetheless is returning false to IsDevelopment().
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the double quotes in the docker-compose.
In fact, in the output they are escaped and dotnet did not recognized the environment.

Comment: Ok..glad you figured it out.  Gaaa, no-quotes, single-quotes, double-quotes !!